# Challenging: How to list all credit cards associated with customer name while selecting the customer name randomly or arbitrarily

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having hard time figuring this query out. Lets say there are list of customer names and credit card associated with it with a given name, i want to display the credit cards associated with them but selecting it arbitrarily or randomly. i tried doing it manually hard-coding the name but i want the query to take the names randomly.

i tried doing it manually hard-coding the name but i want the query to take the names randomly.

MYSQL:

```
SELECT credit_card.`CreditCard#` AS `Creditcard Number`,  customer.customername AS `Name`
FROM credit_card, customer, account
WHERE customer.CustomerName = "Bob white" **
```

This is hardcoded

```
AND holds_account.`Customer#` = customer.`Customer#`
AND credit_card.`CreditCard#` = holds_account.`CreditCard#`
```

i want to display the credit cards associated with them but selecting the names arbitrarily or randomly.
EX customer table: A B A D

Credit Card Number of customer

```
         A: 12321432 
         B: 234324324
         A: 1231312213
         D: 234324433
```

Answer supposed to look like:

```
A 12321432
A 1231312213
```

Names are to be taken randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10`, if you wanted to select 10 records at random.

Example: `SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10`

Comment: In `WHERE customer.CustomerName = "Bob white" `, instead of `"Bob white"` I want to have a (single) name arbitrarily chosen. I tried using `Limit 1` but it sometimes gives null result whereas sometimes gives me required values.

Comment: This is what I did:

SELECT * FROM customer,credit_card,account
WHERE customer.CustomerName = (SELECT customer.CustomerName from customer ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
AND holds_account.`Customer#` = customer.`Customer#`
AND credit_card.`CreditCard#` = account.`CreditCard#`

Comment: It is really helpful to post `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` for all tables involved when asking questions about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to write the SQL using correct `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT c.`CreditCard#`,  
       c.customername AS `Name`
FROM credit_card cc JOIN
     customer c
     ON cc.`Customer#` = c.`Customer#`
```

I don't think `accounts` is needed, but you can add it in if it is.

If you want all credit cars for a random selection o customer, then choose the random customers in a subquery:

```
SELECT c.`CreditCard#`,  
       c.customername AS `Name`
FROM credit_card cc JOIN
     (SELECT c.*
      FROM customer c
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 10
     ) c
     ON cc.`Customer#` = c.`Customer#` ;
```

This assumes that all customers have credit cards.  If this is not the case, then you may need to include logic for that as well:

```
SELECT c.`CreditCard#`,  
       c.customername AS `Name`
FROM credit_card cc JOIN
     (SELECT c2.*
      FROM customer c2
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM credit_card cc2 WHERE cc2.`Customer#` = c.`Customer#`)
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 10
     ) c
     ON cc.`Customer#` = c.`Customer#` ;
```